# Reading up to a character in a text file

Tags: java, file

I remember doing something identical in Python and finding it easy, but I can't seem to find a solution in Java. I basically need to program to read a text file, but only the first part of each line.

The text file currently looks like

test1,Test1
test2,Test2
test3,Test3

I have a validation system so when a user signs up, it checks the username is not already taken. I just need to be able to check the usernames without the passwords, or in other words, read the line up to the comma. I already have the code to check the username and password for the login, which looks like this

```
String user = userText.getText();
String pString = String.valueOf(passwordText.getPassword());
File file = new File("C:/Users/Will/Desktop/UnPs.txt");
boolean found = false;
Scanner scan = null;
try {
    scan = new Scanner(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
while(scan.hasNextLine() && found == false) {           
    String passCheck = scan.nextLine();     
    if(passCheck.equals(user + "," + pString)) {
        System.out.println("Found");
        found = true;
    }
    else if(!passCheck.equals(user + "," + pString)) {
        System.out.println("not found");
    }
}
```

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find anything related to the subject.

Comment: How did you "raed the line up to the comma" in Python?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the spelling mistake i will go find the code now

Comment: @ImNotWill  - `passCheck.split(",")[0]` will give you the string before the comma.

Comment: yeah i used .split when i had similar code in python will try that now

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you can do something like this

```
Scanner read = new Scanner (new File("C:/Users/Will/Desktop/UnPs.txt"));
   read.useDelimiter(",");
   String name, pwd;

   while(read.hasNext())
   {
       name = read.next();
       pwd= read.next();
       
     System.out.println(name+ " " + pwd + "\n"); //just for debugging
   }
   read.close();
```

Or use split method : https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: used the .split() as @ArvindKumarAvinish suggested but i will read up on this method as well thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

maybe too simple, but try

```
...
String nameCheck = scan.nextLine();
if (nameCheck.startsWith(userName + ",")) {
    ...
```

to really get the name of each line:

```
...
String line = scan.nextLine();
int comma = line.indexOf(',');
if (comma != -1) {
  String name = line.substring(0, comma);
  ...
} else {
  //no comma? error message, or just ignore
}
```

or using regular expression   :

```
...
String line = scan.nextLine();
String name = line.replaceFirst(",.*", "");
...
```

<sub>despite I think that regular expression is kind of an overkill here...but neat</sub>